# MongoDB extract subdocument as actual document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document structure like:

```
{
    _id: '323423423fsdr2',
    title: 'hey',
    location: 'Someplace',
    draft: {
        title: 'hey im a draft',
        location: 'Someplace',
    }
}
```

How would I query mongo to get only the draft version, but have it returned as if it were the root level document like:

```
db.collection.find(somequery)
```

returns

```
{
    title: 'hey im a draft',
    location: 'Someplace'
}
```

I am looking into the aggregation framework but I am unsure on how I would even begin. It would be cool if I could avoid extracting the document at the application level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation is the only choice in this case, use `$match` to pass your filter
see more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
            $project : {
                _id : 0,
                title : "$draft.title",
                location : "$draft.location"
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Is this possible without specifying every field? Since the fields may be unknown

Comment: @wazzaday  If my answer helped you please accept it see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer